# How to copy remote server file in document directory in swift

Tags: ios, swift, copy-paste, nsfilemanager, remote-server

I know how to get a remote URL in Swift

```
let remoteURL = NSURL(string: "https://myserver/file.txt")!
```

I know how to get a local URL in Swift

```
let localURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsFolder + "/my_local_file.txt")
```

and unfortunately this does not work

```
NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtURL(remoteURL, toURL: localURL)
```

with the following error

```
The file “file.txt” couldn’t be opened because URL type https isn’t supported.
```

Is there a way how to perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSURLSessionDownloadTask to download the file:

```
func downloadFile(url: URL) {
    let downloadRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: downloadRequest) { location, response, error in
        // To do check resoponse before saving
        guard  let tempLocation = location where error == nil else { return }
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urlsForDirectory(.documentDirectory, inDomains: .userDomainMask).last
        do {
            let fullURL = try documentDirectory?.appendingPathComponent((response?.suggestedFilename!)!)
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: tempLocation, to: fullURL!)
            print("saved at \(fullURL) ")
        } catch NSCocoaError.fileReadNoSuchFileError {
            print("No such file")
        } catch {
            // other errors
            print("Error downloading file : \(error)")
        }
    }.resume()
}

let stringURL = "https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt"
downloadImage(url: URL(string: stringURL)!)
```

**Update: SWIFT 2.2**

```
func downloadFile(url: NSURL) {
    let downloadRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithRequest(downloadRequest){ (location, response, error) in

        guard  let tempLocation = location where error == nil else { return }
        let documentDirectory = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first
        let fullURL = documentDirectory?.URLByAppendingPathComponent((response?.suggestedFilename)!)

        do {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().moveItemAtURL(tempLocation, toURL: fullURL!)
        } catch NSCocoaError.FileReadNoSuchFileError {
            print("No such file")
        } catch {
            print("Error downloading file : \(error)")
        }

        }.resume()
}

 let stringURL = "https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt"
 let url = NSURL.init(string: stringURL)
 downloadFile(url!)
```

Comment: It is Swift 3, I will modify it in a minute.

Comment: Sorry I haven't move to Swift 3, unfortunately I know I should. Please keep Swift 3 version for the future :)

Comment: no need I found the Swift 2.x implementation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29475376/1139044

Answer (score 1):

You should download it first, then save it to a local file.

Code example can be found here: (using `AFNetworking`)

[How I properly setup an AFNetworking Get Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38757740/how-i-properly-setup-an-afnetworking-get-request/38757945#38757945)

Comment: anything swift related?

Comment: It's just a simple piece of code. You can translate it to Swift very easily.

Comment: anything else without the need of importing an external library? Does not exist a simple way in pure Swift with Apple frameworks?

Comment: In the easy way, you can use contentOfUrl to get remote File. But if you want asynchronous, you can use NSURLsession.